# Passing variables with additional parameters from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, shell, escaping

I need to pass a multi-word argument from PHP to Python.

Passing only a single word poses no problem, however, how do I add the additional parameter that will result in a successful solution?

I have tried several ways to pass the additional parameter without any success, it result in either a 500 Internal Server Error or no response from the python script. Using 2>&1 also do not return any error messages.

There are six instances where additional parameter are optional or required for a successful response.

I can send the single word argument:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python /home/nova_api.py 'getwithdrawalhistory' 2>&1");
```

This will return the proper response of:

```
{"items":[],"message":"Your trade history with recent first","page":1,"pages":0,"perpage":100,"status":"success","total_items":0}
```

My attempts to pass the additional parameter from PHP to Python:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python /home/nova_api.py 'getwithdrawalhistory, { \'page\': 1 }' 2>&1");

$command = escapeshellcmd("python /home/nova_api.py 'getwithdrawalhistory, { \'page\': \'1\' }' 2>&1");

$command = escapeshellcmd("python /home/nova_api.py 'getwithdrawalhistory, { \'page\': \"1\" }' 2>&1");
```

All three result in a blank page - no response and no error returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the right thing by escaping, but using `escapeshellcmd` isn't what you want. It has no concept of arguments, so isn't working the way you expect. PHP provides [a method to quote and escape individual arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to shell commands:

```
<?php
$cmd = "python";
$args = [
    "/home/nova_api.py",
    "getwithdrawalhistory, { 'page': 1 }",
];
// just a fancy way of avoiding a foreach loop
$escaped_args = implode(" ", array_map("escapeshellarg", $args));
$command = "$cmd $escaped_args 2>&1";
```

Comment: This code do the same, however, it still result in a blank page or no response. I believe this has something to do with passing an integer from php to python. As a simple work around at this time I make use of four steps; 1 - prepare the command in php \'getwithdrawalhistory\', { \'page\': 1 } , 2 - append the command to the python file using ('fwrite($fp, 'print api_query( \'getwithdrawalhistory\', { \'page\': 1 } )');') , 3 - execute the command and return the results to the php file, 4 - remove the prepared command from the python file from php unset($lines[$last]);.